# Date Range Search using jQuery DatePicker Error

Tags: php, jquery, json

i have created two DatePicker which name are from date,  to date and one seach button for retrieve data.
i am going to search  the records select   from date and to date and click search button  to retrieve data from the database to diplay on datatable. but data coming from the database successfully i checked through console.log.but  it not passing to datatable.i am getting error from the datatable like this ( DataTables warning: table id=tbl-projects - Requested unknown parameter 'vendor_id' for row 0, column 0)

**Form**

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">From Date</label>
                          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="from_date" name="from_date" placeholder="From Date"  required>
              </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
               <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">To Date</label>
                     <input type="date" class="form-control" id="to_date" name="to_date" placeholder="To Date"  required>
               </div>
   </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class=" btn btn-info" id="save" onclick="get_all()">Search</button>
                    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" id="close">Close</button>

                </div>
```

**Table**

```
<table id="tbl-projects" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0"
                   width="100%">
    <thead>
              <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
            </tr>
 </table>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
    function get_all() {
        var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
        var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"all_purchase.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},
            success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    total = data.total
                console.log(data.total);
                $('#tbl-projects').dataTable({
                    "aaData": data
                    ,
                    "scrollX": true,
                    "aoColumns": [
                        {"sTitle": "vendor_id", "mData": "vendor_id"},
                        {"sTitle": "date", "mData": "date"},
                        {"sTitle": "total", "mData": "total"},
                        {"sTitle": "pay", "mData": "pay"},
                        {"sTitle": "due", "mData": "due"},
                        {"sTitle": "payment_type", "mData": "payment_type"}
                    ]
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log('Request Status: ' + xhr.status  );
                console.log('Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText );
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                var text = $($.parseHTML(xhr.responseText)).filter('.trace-message').text();
                // console.log(text)
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Php**

```
if(isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"])){

 $fdate = $_POST["from_date"];
$todate = $_POST["to_date"];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("select vendor_id,date,total,pay,due,payment_type from purs where date BETWEEN '" . $_POST["from_date"] . "' AND '" . $_POST["to_date"] . "' ");
$stmt->bind_result($vendor_id, $date, $total, $pay, $due, $payment_type);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $output[] = array("vendor_id" => $vendor_id, "date" => $date, "total" => $total, "pay" => $pay, "due" => $due, "payment_type" => $payment_type);
    }

    echo json_encode($output);
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: yes sir.console.log(data);   [{"vendor_id":2,"date":"2018-07-02","total":100000,"pay":333,"due":99667,"payment_type":1},{"vendor_id":2,"date":"2018-07-01","total":700000,"pay":600000,"due":100000,"payment_type":1},{"vendor_id":2,"date":"2018-07-02","total":200000,"pay":200000,"due":0,"payment_type":1}]

Comment: i got the  Error.  i missed this line   dataType: 'JSON',  when we get the data from json request thanks